# Add custom request header in Codeception

Tags: java, php, selenium, http-headers, codeception

Currently there is an issue for new Safari 11.1 browser and later that regular login parameters cannot be processed in format: "http(s)://user:pass@host".

There seems to be a way for bypassing this by sending customized request header in Selenium using WebDriverBackedSelenium class.

```
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://<user>:<password>@<host>");
selenium.start("addCustomRequestHeader=true");
selenium.addCustomRequestHeader( "Authorization","Basic "+"YWRpZGFzOmFkaWRhczEyMyM=" );
```

Is theere a way to do this in PHP/Codeception? Since there is no WebDriverBackedSelenium class in codeception, is there some alternative to this which can be used, or some other way of doing this in efficient way?

Comment: There is a capababilities key in *.suite.yml (see https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#Configuration) which supports an addCustomRequestHeaders capability for Firefox at least - possibly there is some way through *.suite.yml that isn't documented? It looks like you can do it per-test with the haveHttpHeader method in the REST and PhpBrowser modules as well.

Comment: Well, currently we are using BrowserStack and I am afraid that we cannot use PhPBrowser modules due to possible collision. Same applies to WebDriver.

Comment: What module are you using to connect to BrowserStack?